# How to do an order two times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this piece of code

```
<% @hours.joins(:worker).order('workers.name').each do |hour| %>

<tr>
  <td><%= hour.worker.name %></td>
  <td><%= hour.job.date</td>
...
```

How can do an order on the hour.job.date after being sorted on worker.name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the columns you want to order by (in your case you'll want to join `jobs` table as well):

```
@hours.joins(:worker, :job).order('workers.name, jobs.date')
```